# How can I convert this to month?

Tags: r

```
6/9/2013 1:15
7/9/2013 1:15
```

I have a series of data in a column of this format.

I am trying to convert it into a month and store it in a different column.

How can I do it?

```
Intended output

June
July
```

I tried using the lubridate library but not able to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
x <- c("6/9/2013 1:15","7/9/2013 1:15")
strftime(as.Date(x, format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"), "%B")
# [1] "June" "July"
```

First convert to a proper date via `as.Date()` then use the formatting options in `strftime` to get the month name.

Comment: Thank you. I am getting this error: Error in `[.data.table`(x, i, which = TRUE) : 
  When i is a data.table (or character vector), x must be keyed (i.e. sorted, and, marked as sorted) so data.table knows which columns to join to and take advantage of x being sorted. Call setkey(x,...) first, see ?setkey.

Comment: all["month"]<-strftime(as.Date(all$start, format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"), "%B")

Where all is the name of the dataframe and start is the name of the column

Comment: Try `all[, month := strftime(as.Date(start, format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"), "%B")]`

Comment: @maximusyoda There's nothing you your question about using a `data.table` (usually I assume `data.frame`). Hopefully @David's response will work. Otherwise update your example to reflect what you are really trying to do.